# How to use Regex Pattern matching

Tags: java, regex

In SQL, we can search using like keyword. 
ex,

```
1. Pattern
2. Putty
```

These words can retrieved using query : `like 'P_tt%'`

How can i do the same process in java.

Comment: post what have you tried

Comment: Can you accept my answer if it helped you? or please say what should I correct.

Comment: `List<String> tList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(new String[]          {"Putty","Pattern","Pety","PPP","satt"}));
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile("P_tt\\.*");
   for(String str : tList)
   {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    boolean b = m.matches();
    log.info("str >> "+str+" b >> "+b);
   }`  @Michal - I had tried this. It returns only false. Is it correct the way i tested?

Answer (score 1):

You can use java.util.regex.Pattern.
Example:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("a*b");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

In your case it would be:

```
 Pattern p = Pattern.compile("P_tt\\.*");
 Matcher m = p.matcher("aaaaab");
 boolean b = m.matches();
```

For more visit Java documentation:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You may something like this:

```
String str1 = "MyString lalaa";
String str2 = "P_tt other string lala";
String pattern = "P_tt\\.*";
boolean isInStr1 = str1.matches(pattern); // return false
boolean isInStr2 = str2.matches(pattern); // return true
```

But keep in mind, that `LIKE` doesn't search by regexp pattern. In Java you may use simple regexp patterns. In my example I suggested "`P_tt\.*`", that mean "`P_tt`" - your constant word and "`\.`" - any character(include whitespaces, tabs and other), and `*` is mean amount iteration. `*` - zero or more.